# Using Mercurial (hg), is there a way to diff rev 4873 and 4821 but only for my changes?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I want to know what changes I made, without looking at the 30 other files that other team members modified.

So when I `hg out`, it said the first changeset to push was 4821, so since then I have pulled, merged, and pushed a couple times.  Now I want to make sure all the debugging code is removed.  Is there a way to diff the current revision (4873) against revision 4821 but only for my changes?

Answer (score 1):

If your changes are in different files than those of your coworkers, which is how it sounds, you can use something like this:

```
hg diff -r 4821 -r 4863 -I path/to/file1 -I path/to/file2
```

If they're mixed in the same files as other people's changes then you would have needed to keep your changes in a separate branch (which doesn't require the `branch` command, anonymous branching is commonly used for this sort of thing).

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick:

```
hg diff -r "4821:4873 and user(your_username)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can upgrade to the recently release Mercurial 1.6 or not, but this [functional query language](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) feature they just put in is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. First clone your local repo to another folder
2. In the new clone, rebase your last changeset so that it immediately follows your the other changeset (this should create a new head from it)
3. Do the diff

Comment: I get the impression he has multiple changesets interspersed with theirs and merged back a few times, so I don't think he can separate them with a rebase.